# Provide an OnChange event for an internal property which is controlled externally?

Tags: delphi, class-design

For fun and by request I am updating [this ImageGrid component](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8954813/757830), a kind of listbox for images that has a `FileNames` property of type `TStrings`.

For ease of writing, I have been misusing its `FileNames.Objects` property for bitmap storage. But since the `TStrings` type suggests that users of the component could or would want to use the `Objects` property for custom data, e.g. like `TListBox.Items`, I am rewriting the component to store the bitmaps elsewhere and leave `FileNames.Objects` untouched for unknown future usage.

Now I am wondering whether to provide an `OnChange` event. And if so, whether to fire it when one or more `FileNames.Objects` changes.

Trying to answer it myself, I dove in Delphi's own VCL and stumbled on:

- `TMemo`: has an `OnChange` event, but ignores `Lines.Objects`
- `TListBox`: has no `OnChange` event, but is capable of storing `Items.Objects`
- `TStringGrid`: has no `OnChange` event, but is capable of storing `Objects`, `Rows.Objects`, `Cols.Objects`

So now I am somewhat puzzeled, because I cannot imagine Borland's developers didn't add events for several `Objects` properties out of ease. Sure, when a user changes a `FileNames.Object` in my component, he knows he does and could implement appropriate interaction himself. But wouldn't it be convenient when the component does automatically?

What would you expect from this component in this regard?